# on the generating series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_a(n)}{n}x^n$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I was reading about the divisor function on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), and I stumbled upon the formula
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_a(n)}{n^s}=\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a).$$
Here $\sigma_a(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^a$ for an integer $a\geq 0$. Let us fix $s=1$. The sum still makes sense but does not converge anymore to the right hand side. However my question is not about the sum $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_a(n)}{n}$. I was wondering if the generating function associated to the sequence $\frac{\sigma_a(n)}{n}$ is known:

> *Question*: If $x$ is a formal variable, how can we express the power
>   series $$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_a(n)}{n}x^n,$$  e.g. is it a
>   rational function, an infinite product, or anything else related to $\zeta$, or...?

Comment: Is there any reason you think that the power series has a nice expression?

Comment: I have no idea whether it has a nice expression, except for the existence of a "nice" expression for a similar generating series, namely $\sum_{n\geq 1}\sigma_a(n)x^n$ (found again on that page of Wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you are dealing with multiplicative functions (which $\sigma_a(n)/n$ is) you get [Lambert Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series) (in fact, I was amused to see that when I was looking for the link, I saw that the wikipedia article had exactly this example).

Comment: Thank you, @IgorRivin. Could you please expand a little bit on your answer? As the Wikipedia article refers to the sum $\sum \sigma_a(n)x^n$, I do not understand if you are meaning that we have, even for our sum, the equality $\sum_n (\sigma_a(n)/n)x^n=\sum_m(\sum_{d|m}\sigma_a(d)/d)x^m$.